# PrestaShop: web service issue on $cart->getCartRules()

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using PrestaShop for a long time, I create a web service to execute many specific requests.
In one case and when I try to add a voucher to my cart I got a 500 error and this is my code:

```
$cartresult = $cart->addCartRule(264362);
$cartRules = $cart->getCartRules();
var_dump($cart);
```

the error appears in the second line.

Comment: Check the Web server logs

Comment: Where i can found them ?

Comment: Depends on the Web server (Apache, Nginx etc.) configuration =)

Comment: Ok, i'll check.

Comment: Have you enabled the developer mode in `prestashop/config/defines.inc.php`? Set `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to true and check if display an error. Which version of prestashop are you using?

Comment: version 1.6.1 i did it. finaly i found that there is a restriction made it by operators, they not allow some group's customers to use some vouchers.